# WPF Equivalent to Flex VGroup

Tags: wpf, apache-flex, alignment

**What is WPF equivalent to Flex VGroup?**
My Intent is to have a vertical list of checkboxes
Flex declaration would look like this

```
<s:VGroup>
  <s:CheckBox label="Item 1" />
  <s:CheckBox label="Item 2" />
  <s:CheckBox label="Item 3" />
</s:VGroup>
```

I have fooled around with Grid without much success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should do the job.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
...
</StackPanel>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx